# Oracle Insert with select followed by another query

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle11gr2

I'm trying to insert data into a table but I need to select all of the data from a table and another query into the table to be inserted.
The insert query is something like this:

```
insert into table_a
select * from table_b, to_date(my_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

I need to convert value from the selected table and covert into date format and insert in into the new table. So, the `table_a` has one more column than `table_b`. I've tried a number of ways but it hasn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like below

```
insert into table_a
select g.*,to_date(my_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') from table_b g
```

which will give one more column apart from table_b

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. The column I'm trying to convert to date is varchar2 with format 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.ff'. I tried to use the same format and I get the error - 
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Comment: check the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` of `nlsparam` in `TO_DATE`